# Identifying positivity and negativity separately from a negative dataset

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, classification, text-classification

First of all, i would like you to know that I am new to machine learning (ML). I am working on a project which detects how **positive or negative** a set of words can be, therefore i have created a database containing possible **negative** words. So that ML can take place and predict the overall score on how **positive or negative** the whole set of words. 
My questions are is it possible to classify **positive** words with only  **negative** words in the dataset? Does it affect the accuracy of predicting if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not generally possible.  The model will have no way to differentiate among (1) new negative phrases; (2) neutral phrases; (3) positive phrases.  In fact, with only negative phrases, the model will have a hard time learning that "bad" and "not bad" are opposites, as it has seen plenty of "not" references in the negative literature, such as "not worth watching, even for free."